# issue parsing Twitter JSON in Google App Script

Tags: json, twitter, google-apps-script

I'm using the code described in the [GAS documentation](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1) to retrieve my Twitter timeline. 
The lines

```
 var response = twitterService.fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=1');
 response=response.getContentText();
```

yield the following result:

```
[{"created_at":"Sun Jan 14 15:30:00 +0000 2018","id":952563458616172544,"id_str":"952563458616172544","text":"#UltimOra, \u201cAi piedi le Clarks\u201d; #LiberieUguali trova il primo punto di convergenza fra i vari leader https:\/\/omissis","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"UltimOra","indices":[0,9]},{"text":"LiberieUguali","indices":[33,47]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/omissis","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.lercio.it\/ai-piedi-le-clarks-liberi-e-uguali-trova-il-primo-punto-di-convergenza-fra-i-vari-leader\/","display_url":"lercio.it\/ai-piedi-le-cl\u2026","indices":[102,125]}]},"source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/about.twitter.com\/products\/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTweetDeck\u003c\/a\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":910827588,"id_str":"910827588","name":"lercio-notizie","screen_name":"lercionotizie","location":"","description":"Dal 13 aprile 2017 in fumetteria e libreria con \"Lercio, lo sporco che fa notizia. Il libro\" (Shockdom)","url":"http:\/\/omissis","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/omissis","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.lercio.it","display_url":"lercio.it","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":491614,"friends_count":25,"listed_count":712,"created_at":"Sun Oct 28 18:19:33 +0000 2012","favourites_count":385,"utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"Amsterdam","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":7335,"lang":"it","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/696203701\/001bc779080491195bc16054af629016.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/696203701\/001bc779080491195bc16054af629016.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2932719853\/4bcd23b39293870bf1832aec72b6fe3d_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2932719853\/4bcd23b39293870bf1832aec72b6fe3d_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/910827588\/1467828171","profile_link_color":"9B1212","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":true,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false,"translator_type":"none"},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":73,"favorite_count":186,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"possibly_sensitive_appealable":false,"lang":"it"}]
```

But when I add the code line

```
response=JSON.parse(response);
```

the JSON file is totally altered, it doesn't even look a JSON file and its content becomes:

```
{possibly_sensitive_appealable=false, in_reply_to_status_id_str=null, in_reply_to_status_id=null, created_at=Sun Jan 14 15:30:00 +0000 2018, in_reply_to_user_id_str=null, source=<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>, retweet_count=73, retweeted=false, geo=null, in_reply_to_screen_name=null, is_quote_status=false, id_str=952563458616172544, in_reply_to_user_id=null, favorite_count=186, id=9.5256345861617254E17, text=#UltimOra, “Ai piedi le Clarks”; #LiberieUguali trova il primo punto di convergenza fra i vari leader https://omissis, place=null, lang=it, favorited=false, possibly_sensitive=false, coordinates=null, truncated=false, entities={urls=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7d41de2d, hashtags=[Ljava.lang.Object;@5e05507d, user_mentions=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7b5572f2, symbols=[Ljava.lang.Object;@fb373c9}, contributors=null, user={utc_offset=3600, friends_count=25, profile_image_url_https=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2932719853/4bcd23b39293870bf1832aec72b6fe3d_normal.png, listed_count=712, profile_background_image_url=http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/696203701/001bc779080491195bc16054af629016.png, default_profile_image=false, favourites_count=385, description=Dal 13 aprile 2017 in fumetteria e libreria con "Lercio, lo sporco che fa notizia. Il libro" (Shockdom), created_at=Sun Oct 28 18:19:33 +0000 2012, is_translator=false, profile_background_image_url_https=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/696203701/001bc779080491195bc16054af629016.png, protected=false, screen_name=lercionotizie, id_str=910827588, profile_link_color=9B1212, is_translation_enabled=false, translator_type=none, id=910827588, geo_enabled=false, profile_background_color=FFFFFF, lang=it, has_extended_profile=false, profile_sidebar_border_color=000000, profile_text_color=333333, verified=false, profile_image_url=http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2932719853/4bcd23b39293870bf1832aec72b6fe3d_normal.png, time_zone=Amsterdam, url=http://omissis, contributors_enabled=false, profile_background_tile=false, profile_banner_url=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/910827588/1467828171, entities={description={urls=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7c7074a4}, url={urls=[Ljava.lang.Object;@80245ef}}, statuses_count=7335, follow_request_sent=false, followers_count=491614, profile_use_background_image=true, default_profile=false, following=true, name=lercio-notizie, location=, profile_sidebar_fill_color=DDEEF6, notifications=false}}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `Logger.log` for checking results of code execution.

As noted in [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171231071355/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#logging_custom_messages):

> The method `Logger.log` **expects a string value**, but if you pass in an *object* or *array* **it will do its best** to convert that into a string.

So `response` in this case `response=response.getContentText()` will give you `String` with expected behaviour when used in `Logger.log`, but in case `response=JSON.parse(response)` will give `Object`, that will have output in `Logger.log` in format **`[key1=val1, key2=val2, ..]`**.

You can get used to it, or you can use convertion of your object to string before logging it:

`Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: You caught it! Thank you.